# Spring not picking up changes to ConfigMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, configmap

I have an application that is using Springboot, I am trying to allow on the fly configuration updates using the following.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1-RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have tried to follow this article https://medium.com/swlh/kubernetes-configmap-confuguration-and-reload-strategy-9f8a286f3a44, and have managed to get Spring pulling the config from the ConfigMap, however, if I update the ConfigMap when the application is running, spring does not pick it up. This is my `bootstrap.yml`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      config:
        enabled: true
        sources:
          - namespace: default
            name: hello-world
      reload:
        enabled: true
        mode: event
        strategy: refresh
```

I have also tried using `mode: polling`, but still no change. And I have added the `view` role.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: {{ include "hello-world.fullname" . }}-view
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
  # Authorize specific service accounts:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: {{ include "hello-world.serviceAccountName" . }}
    namespace: default
```

I am thinking maybe it's the way I am loading my configuration in Java?

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.app")
@Bean
public Properties appProperties() {
    return new Properties();
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("appProperties")
private Properties props;
```

My ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: hello-world
data:
  application.yml: |-
    spring:
      app:
        message: Hello
```

I am then accessing values like `props.getProperty("message")`

**UPDATE:**

So I managed to get the changes picked up, by enabling the actuator refresh endpoint:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    restart:
      enabled: true
```

But now I have a new question, is this necessary? Is there any way to get this to work without including the actuator?

Comment: From conceptual point of view, 1) something external calls spring boot application and tells it refresh the context 2) There is no endpoint to call spring boot app to tell it to refresh, instead it keeps polling the configuration with a configured time, if it changed and it refreshes the context. So I guess you have done the first and I don't know if spring boot has built in mechanism for 2) or you have to built it using `@Scheduler`

Comment: Reloading of config is working but the Spring bean which is using this property is not getting refreshed. Do we need to add additional configuration to make dependent bean also getting refreshed ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have the following dependency in your POM with a version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I had similar issue, which is resolved after adding this.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to add `@RefreshScope` to the bean that you want to hot reload with inject with values from config maps.